# Subscription to Message through Microsoft Graph API Without User Interaction

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, office365, microsoft-graph-api, azure-webjobs

I am trying to create an application that subscribes to mail events (New mails, Create,update) in office 365 using Microsoft Graph APIs without user interaction. If there is a new email I want to send a notification to my app which has been built using C# MVC5 and .Net 4.5. An example I am following is in Github here (using Daemon Service
[Github project Link](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-daemon-v2))
but it has been built in .Net Core. I came across another application which uses WebJobs and is very close to my requirement
[Azure webjobs](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/webjobs-webhooks-sample) but it has not been updated in the last 2 years. I followed the steps but most of them do not match with my Azure Developer Account (free). Can some one help me on this please?

App settings :

App Settings:

```
<add key="tenantId" value="[Tenant_ID]" />
    <add key="clientId" value="[AppID]" />
    <add key="clientSecret" value="[Client Secret]" />
    <add key="webjobs" value="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=onvidawebjob1aa1b;AccountKey=Z3xewALbEc43gE/dL06HxCGIjVtpaiTkIY4ZolkjZt9Z86xHIZLzMwXBlujNI8/PcTJbM1LIs5KNceVTGgESmA==" />
    <add key="subscriptionblobname" value="subscriptions/subscription1" />
    <add key="notificationurl" value="https://onvidawebjob1.azurewebsites.net/api/HttpTrigger1?code=H7liZOlcQc5qjcZOkRXEb0x4JVqTzoXnrl6mAswsEKl4LlmAYm/ACw==" />
```

i tried to recreate the app got below issue Trace

```
Development settings applied
Found the following functions:
WebHooksSample.Functions.ManageSubscriptions
WebHooksSample.Functions.OnNotificationReceived
Singleton lock acquired (cd016b3464fa4d8aa8f41f884a064168/WebHooksSample.Functions.ManageSubscriptions.Listener)
Function 'WebHooksSample.Functions.ManageSubscriptions' is configured to run on startup. Executing now.
Executing 'Functions.ManageSubscriptions' (Reason='Timer fired at 2018-11-16T19:05:27.4182054+05:30', Id=155f7f8a-c352-427f-a7c3-a55ab3518c9a)
Exception while executing function: Functions.ManageSubscriptions
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionInvocationException: Exception while executing function: Functions.ManageSubscriptions ---> System.Net.Http.HttpR
equestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request).
   at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
   at WebHooksSample.Functions.<ManageSubscriptions>d__14.MoveNext() in D:\354132\office365_sample_app\webjobs\webjobs-webhooks-sample-master\WebHooks
Sample\Functions.cs:line 128
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionInvoker`1.<InvokeAsync>d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.<InvokeAsync>d__22.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.<ExecuteWithWatchersAsync>d__21.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.<ExecuteWithLoggingAsync>d__19.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.<ExecuteWithLoggingAsync>d__13.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
Exception while executing function: Functions.ManageSubscriptions
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionInvocationException: Exception while executing function: Functions.ManageSubscriptions ---> System.Net.Http.HttpR
equestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request).
   at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
   at WebHooksSample.Functions.<ManageSubscriptions>d__14.MoveNext() in D:\354132\office365_sample_app\webjobs\webjobs-webhooks-sample-master\WebHooks
Sample\Functions.cs:line 128
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionInvoker`1.<InvokeAsync>d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.<InvokeAsync>d__22.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.<ExecuteWithWatchersAsync>d__21.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at `enter code here`System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.<ExecuteWithLoggingAsync>d__19.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.<ExecuteWithLoggingAsync>d__13.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.<ExecuteWithLoggingAsync>d__13.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.<TryExecuteAsync>d__10.MoveNext()
The next 5 occurrences of the schedule will be:
11/16/2018 7:06:03 PM
11/16/2018 7:06:33 PM
11/16/2018 7:07:03 PM
11/16/2018 7:07:33 PM
11/16/2018 7:08:03 PM
Job host started
Executing 'Functions.ManageSubscriptions' (Reason='Timer fired at 2018-11-16T19:05:57.4122054+05:30', Id=405fe97b-2b8a-48bb-a761-7c46a293622c)
Exception while executing function: Functions.ManageSubscriptions
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionInvocationException: Exception while executing function: Functions.ManageSubscriptions ---> System.Net.Http.HttpR
equestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request).
   at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
   at WebHooksSample.Functions.<ManageSubscriptions>d__14.MoveNext() in D:\354132\office365_sample_app\webjobs\webjobs-webhooks-sample-master\WebHooks
Sample\Functions.cs:line
```

**EDIT 1:**

I was able to accomplish receiving emails (without a user logging in) using outlook connector and office 365 webhook API (using default connector available in azure logic App) similar to what is described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/publish-iot-hub-events-to-logic-apps). However, outlook connector polls for every x seconds (custom value set by me) for any change in the mailbox, but I want the service to automatically trigger the Webhook Event without polling. If I understand it correctly, it should be like this -

1. Create a webhook that is registered to watch for events
2. Create an outlook connector that uses above webhook.
3. Outlook connector notifies application (REST API call) as part of workflow.

Comment: Are you looking for the initial creation of the subscription to be without user interaction, or are you looking for the subsequent notifications to not require user interaction?

Comment: Did you try it with powershell? https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/cloudlojik/2017/09/05/using-powershell-to-connect-to-microsoft-graph-api/

Comment: initial as well as subsequent request it shouldn't ask for credential , because already they have signed with my existing app , if there additional log-in that would annoying the user,

Comment: Updated on my side ,somehow i managed to accomplish the above requirement with outlook connector and office 365 webhook API (default connector available in azure logic App)  but still outlook connector polls for every x seconds( custom value set by me ) for any change in the mailbox, but i'm looking for without polling it should automatically trigger the Webhook Event. i'm still hoping for any other solutions

Answer (score 2):

Here are some key points to consider:

- Working with Microsoft Graph webhook notifications is the same no matter what language/platform you are using. The only difference is how/where you host your notification endpoint.
- To subscribe to notifications without user interaction, your app needs app-only permissions

You may want to look into Azure Functions; they provide some easy to work with bindings for Microsoft Graph: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-microsoft-graph